# Python prints unwanted extra newline

Tags: python, input, newline

Why is that Python always prints an extra newline when I run the code below? I tried to re-write the code to eliminate any unintended blank space but it still prints out an extra new line. Anyone knows why? Thanks.

```
def main():
    names_in()                          #This function import the file and read all the content and put the content into a list. 

    print_names(names_in)        # Before the names are sorted.

def names_in():
    infile = open('names.txt','r')
    names_list = []                 #empty list.
    names = infile.readline()   # read contents.

    #loop for continue to read.
    while names != '':
        names = infile.readline()       #continue to the next name.
        names = names.rstrip('\n')    #return a copy of the string which all \n has been stripped from the end of the string.
        names_list.append(names)    #write names in the file into a list.
    infile.close()

    return names_list                     #return the list back to the function.



def print_names(names_in):        #This function will print out the names in the list one per line, single-spaced.
    for item in names_in():
        print(item)


main()
```

This in my input file:

```
Riggs, Jerry
Stone, Ruby
Wood, Holly
Dover, Ilene
Funt, Ella
Storm, Wayne
Lowe, Lyle
Free, Bjorn
Caine, Candy
Carr, Rex
Downs, Mark
Twain, Lionel
Thorn, Rose
Shore, Rocky
Bush, Rose
Waters, Muddy
Graves, Doug
Stone, Roxanne
Rivers, Wade
```

Comment: You read the input file twice; you don't need to call `names_in()` first and discard the results, if `print_names()` calls it again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code prints an extra newline is because in the last iteration of the `names_in` function, the variable `names` is ``, which gets appended to the end of `names_list`, causing the `print_names` function to run `print ''` at the end, which prints an extra newline.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there anyway I could fix this? I don't know how to modify the loop so that it could read every line in the file and not print an extra newline at the same time.