# How to print elements from a for loop into a list?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
for y in range(5):
numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)]  # generates 100 random numbers from 1-10
print(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count))  # prints out one of which appeared the most
```

And when I run that code, the output is:

```
1
8
3
6
4
```

But I want the output to be: `1, 8, 3, 6, 4`

I tried appending it to a new list, but I keep getting an error that says 'int' has no attribute 'append'.

I also tried making it a string by typing:

`new_list = str(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count` but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python prints unwanted extra newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704380/python-prints-unwanted-extra-newline)

Comment: did you call it like this: `new_list=[]; new_list.append(whatever)`? because that should fix the Attribute error, at least.

Comment: I suspect the new_list method is actually creating a new list at each pass. Can you pass each print value into an array/list until you hit <=y and then print that array/list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or like this,

```
>>> x = [max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count) for numbers in [[random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)] for y in range(5)]]
>>> ', '.join(str(_) for _ in x)
>>> '2, 10, 7, 5, 8'
```

Comment: you need to use str() otherwise join() throws a TypeError

Comment: or `', '.join(map(str, x))`

Comment: I never liked map :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
new = list()
for y in range(5):
    numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)]  # generates 100 random numbers from 1-10
    new.append(str(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count)))  # prints out one of which appeared the most
print new  # Prints whole list
print ", ".join(new) # Prints comma separated values in one line
```

Output:

```
['10', '8', '6', '8', '2']
10, 8, 6, 8, 2
```

Comment: thank you, exactly what i was looking for.. still very new to python

Comment: @Flob i have already appended str values so no need for mapping str values

Comment: yup, sorry for that :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you want to collate the results you print into a list before printing. So all you need to do is create a new list and append results to it. You can just print the result, but if you want to avoid the brackets, you can convert your results into string and then use join() string function

```
results = []
for y in range(5):
    numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)]
    results.append(str(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count)))
print(', '.join(results))
```

This gives me output like

`7, 2, 4, 3, 2`

Answer (score 0):

for output to be literally horizontal use this :

```
for y in range(5):
numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)]  # generates 100 random numbers from 1-10
print(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count) , end =", ")
```

if you want to use your output  in a different variable use this:

```
for y in range(5): numbers = [(max(set(random.randint(1, 10),key=numbers.count))) for x in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your 'for' loop you need to append the number you want to add to your list. To do that, you need to create an empty list before your loop:

```
numbers = []
```

Then, your loop will be:

```
for y in range(5):
  numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(100)]
  numbers.append(max(set(numbers), key=numbers.count))
```

Then, after your loop, you can print your list normally:

```
#Prints your desired numbers.
vals = ""
for i in range(len(numbers)):
  vals = vals + numbers[i] + ", "
print(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `print(number, end=', ')`. This will append a string with `,` instead of new line separator in stdout.